# "Why might that be?" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does it mean- "why might that be? " This is the complete sentence:If America’s universities are indeed poor value for money, why might that be?

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused; why might that be?

Well, you might be confused because you are not sure what "that" refers to.
In the above case, "that" refers to the whole first clause: "You seem confused". In the example you gave, "that" refers to the whole first clause: If American universities are indeed poor value for [the] money"

On the other hand, you might be confused as to why the sentence ends with a question. In the example given, it is likely a **rhetorical question**, which the author himself will answer in subsequent text, rather than a real question, which would call for a response from you, the reader.

Comment: +1 - Not only rhetorical, but slightly sarcastic in tone.

Comment: You're welcome. Please if you are satisfied with my answer, accept it (with the little checkmark). That way, your question won't continue to show on the site as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially just asking the reason or reasons for the fact previously stated. The 'might' gives an idea of potential or unknown reasons, to allow slightly more breadth to the answer.